# Why is today's announcement (23/09/2022) a mini budget and not an actual budget

Tags: united-kingdom, budget

Today's announcement by Kwasi Kwarteng has been called a [mini-budget.](https://www.theguardian.com/uk-news/mini-budget-2022)
Given that it's included changes to income tax, national insurance, corporation tax, Stamp Duty, IR35, Strike legislation and Bankers' bonuses among its headlines with cost estimates starting at £100bn what makes this a "mini" budget and how does a "mini-budget" differ from an ordinary budget announcement?

Comment: Number and scope of changes. This budget had far fewer changes than a normal one.

Comment: @SteveMelnikoff can that be backed by figures? If only because the headline of the 2021 [budget](https://www.gov.uk/government/topical-events/budget-2021) was a £65bn business support and today's announcement had £60bn for the energy cap, £19bn for the corp tax and so on. The scope seems pretty big.

Answer (score 2):

A budget is normally an annual event, scheduled well in advance, and deals with government revenue and spending for the forthcoming financial year. As such, it typically contains a large number of changes and initiatives.

By comparison, this statement from the Chancellor was arranged at relatively short notice, and (a) is an early opportunity for the new PM (through her Chancellor) to implement some of the policies mentioned in her leadership campaign, and (b) is a response to specific events (cost of living crisis, high inflation, etc). There is overlap between the two, as the intention appears to use the former (encouraging growth) to help with the latter. Note that this is [not without controversy](https://ifs.org.uk/articles/mini-budget-response).

Another indication that this is something different from the normal annual budget is that the government aren't calling it a budget at all; they're referring to it as "[The Growth Plan 2022](https://www.gov.uk/government/publications/the-growth-plan-2022-documents)". Compare that to the most recent budget, which the government referred to as, well, [Budget 2021](https://www.gov.uk/government/topical-events/budget-2021).

Ultimately, it doesn't really matter what anyone calls it, as the name has no official status. Therefore, people - and the government - are free to refer to it however they like.

Comment: Is there anything required for an official budget that wasn't required here? OBR forecast, opposition notice?

Comment: This is all semantics. It doesn't matter what anyone calls it. But, if one had to provide a definition, then see the first paragraph: a budget normally concerns itself with a wide range of matters for the forthcoming financial year, and is not in response to any particular event. This mini-budget covers a limited number of matters as a quick fix for a specific problem.

Comment: @Jontia You also often get mini-budgets when a new government takes office, in order to quickly implement money-related campaign pledges. That is also true of this one.

Comment: [This](https://www.instituteforgovernment.org.uk/explainers/budgets) says budgets are subject to parimentary scrutiny and voted on. This mini budget doesn't seem to have had that despite including spending plans and taxs cuts that appear larger than the last budget. It doesn't seem semantic to ask why this difference exists and what prevents all future budgets going this 'mini' route.

Comment: Is it really a quick fix to a specific problem? What problem? If it's the cost of living crisis, then a lot of measures don't seem to address that (abolition of banker's bonus cap). It seems to be more of a case of a new leader wanting to impose their ideas and overturn the previous leader's actions as soon as possible.

Comment: @Jontia Budgets have a lot more scrutiny, in the form of a multi-day debate and a series of votes on specific proposals, followed by a bill (normally called the Finance Bill) to implement all the measures, with all the normal scrutiny that a bill has. This mini-budget had a much shorter debate and just one vote (on immediate stamp duty changes), but there will be legislation to follow next month.

Comment: @StuartF Fair point. I'll amend my answer as, on reflection, it appears to be much more about Truss/Kwarteng making their mark in the form of a "Growth Plan", and less about the cost of living.